# json call from php twitter api

Tags: php, json, twitter

```
$content = $connection->get('statuses/public_timeline');
```

. When I use this fragment in my php file. I would like to echo $content[0].text from result array that shown below:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [in_reply_to_user_id_str] => 
        [coordinates] => 
        [geo] => 
        [user] => stdClass Object
            (
                [profile_sidebar_border_color] => a166d9
                [followers_count] => 40
                ...
            )

        [truncated] => 
        [text] => some dump text
        ...
    )
...
 )
```

How will I access [text] or [profile_sidebar_border_color]. What is the PHP syntax? Should I decode?

Comment: I suggest setting the 'true' flag for the 2nd arg in json encode (json_decode($your_data,true)). This makes the return data into numeric and associative arrays. I consider the mix of arrays and objects to be a pain in PHP, since the syntax is different but if the object has no methods, they do the *same thing* so there's no reason to mix them. Check out the json decode docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```
$content[0]->text
```

for the text and

```
$content[0]->user->profile_sidebar_border_color
```

For the user's profile sidebar border color